# How can i find out names of uploaded files using 'CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler' do_POST?

Tags: python, cgi, filenames, cgihttprequesthandler

query = cgi.parse_multipart(handler.rfile, pdict)
I used function "parse_multipart" of module cgi to convert the  form data, but i can not find the name of uploaded file in the content of  variable "query"? where i can find the file's name. Thanks!

Comment: The name of the uploaded file should be the value associated with  the 'filename' attribute in the dictionary returned by cgi.parse_multipart().  Specifically, `query['filename']`.